# Convert Flat XML file into an Nested XML and change the element Name

Tags: xml, xslt

I am able to convert a csv to XML. My problem is i need to convert it into a well formatted XML (nested XML). Also I need to change the element names. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

My flat XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>

<row>
<canName>Victor</canName>
<canID>ABC07</canID>
<courseName>Basic English</courseName>
<canScore>91%</canScore>
<place>School</place>
<examDate>January 01, 2015</examDate>
<title>Mr.</title>
<canTeacher>John</canTeacher>
<tId>GD5</tId>
</row>

<row>
<canName>Victor</canName>
<canID>ABC07</canID>
<courseName>Advanced English</courseName>
<canScore>95%</canScore>
<place>School</place>
<examDate>January 01, 2015</examDate>
<title>Mr.</title>
<canTeacher>John</canTeacher>
<tId>GD5</tId>
</row>

<row>
<canName>Tia</canName>
<canID>ABC01</canID>
<courseName>Basic English</courseName>
<canScore>90%</canScore>
<place>School</place>
<examDate>January 01, 2015</examDate>
<title>Mr.</title>
<canTeacher>John</canTeacher>
<tId>GD5</tId>
</row>

</data>
```

I want to convert it into following nested XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<candidates>

<candidate canName="Victor" canID="ABC07">

<course courseName="Basic English">
<score>91%</score>
<place>School</place>
<examDate>January 01, 2015</examDate>
<title>Mr.</title>
<canTeacher>John</canTeacher>
<tID>GD5</tID>
</course>

<course courseName="Advanced English">
<score>95%</score>
<place>School</place>
<examDate>January 01, 2015</examDate>
<title>Mr.</title>
<canTeacher>John</canTeacher>
<tID>GD5</tID>
</course>

</candidate>

<candidate canName="Tia" userID="ABC01">

<course courseName="Basic English">
<score>90%</score>
<place>School</place>
<examDate>January 01, 2015</examDate>
<title>Mr.</title>
<canTeacher>John</canTeacher>
<tID>GD5</tID>
</course>

<course courseName="Advanced English">
<score>92%</score>
<place>School</place>
<examDate>January 01, 2015</examDate>
<title>Mr.</title>
<canTeacher>John</canTeacher>
<tID>GD5</tID>
</course>

</candidate>

</candidates>
```

Comment: Here's a pointer in the right direction. Read a lot of XSLT answers here on the site or elsewhere. Get started. Come up with a solution that solves at least part of your problem. Come back when you have some code to show. Currently this question is: Dropping your requirements into StackOverflow and hoping someone will do your job for you.

Comment: This is actually a *grouping* question. Do a search: it's probably the most often asked question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.